# Negation of logical constants

Tags: logic, terminology

Broadly, my question is whether is it possible to negate a constant in logic. I'll try to explain. Take a set $\{1,2,3\}$, and say that 1 = $a$. Is it possible to say $\neg a$? If yes, wouldn't $\neg a$ become a variable? (either 2 or 3, given the previous set). I find it strange because it is a way of turning constants into variables, but at the same time I couldn't find any source in which it is explicitely said that you cannot negate a constant. Thank you!!

Comment: NO. We negate formulas i.e. statements and not terms i.e. names. Like natural language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let the universe be the set $\{-4,-3,-2,-1,1,2,3,4\}.$

1. If $B=\{1\},$ then the **complement** of $B,$ denoted by $B^c,$ is
   $\{-4,-3,-2,-1,2,3,4\}.$
2. The **additive inverse** of the element $-3,$ obtained by
   **negating** it (flipping its sign), is $3.$
3. The **negation** of the statement $3\in B,$ obtained by **negating**
   it (flipping its truth value), is $3\notin B.$

No variable is involved in any of the above!